# On Spring-XD analytic-pmml stream, publishing json data via mqtt broker error?

Tags: mqtt, spring-xd

this is my stream definition-

```
xd:>stream create test --definition "mqtt --url='tcp://localhost:1883' --topics='irisPayload'| analytic-pmml --location='/home/andy/Desktop/iris-flower-naive-bayes.pmml.xml' --inputFieldMapping='sepalLength:Sepal.Length,sepalWidth:Sepal.Width,petalLength:Petal.Length,petalWidth:Petal.Width'--outputFieldMapping='Predicted_Species:predictedSpecies' | file" --deploy
```

Created and deployed new stream 'test'

when I am trying to publish JSON data

```
{
  "sepalLength": "6.4",
  "sepalWidth":  "3.2",
  "petalLength": "4.5",
  "petalWidth":  "1.5"
}
```

via broker getting error. complete error is as follows:-

```
2017-03-11T12:24:30+0530 1.3.1.RELEASE ERROR MQTT Call: xd.mqtt.client.id.src inbound.MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter - Unhandled exception for GenericMessage [payload={
  "sepalLength": "6.4",
  "sepalWidth":  "3.2",
  "petalLength": "4.5",
  "petalWidth":  "1.5"
}, headers={mqtt_retained=false, mqtt_qos=0, id=fa97c439-5896-dc53-6c4a-7a8af57b73de, mqtt_topic=irisPayload, mqtt_duplicate=false, timestamp=1489215270746}]

org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: Failed to transform Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.springframework.xd.tuple.Tuple
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:95) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.mqtt.inbound.MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.messageArrived(MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:314) ~[spring-integration-mqtt-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsCallback.handleMessage(CommsCallback.java:354) [org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsCallback.run(CommsCallback.java:162) [org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.2.jar!/:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.springframework.xd.tuple.Tuple
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:96) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer.java:90) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:89) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.springframework.xd.tuple.Tuple
    at org.springframework.xd.analytics.ml.pmml.TuplePmmlAnalyticInputDataMapper.mapInput(TuplePmmlAnalyticInputDataMapper.java:37) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.xd.analytics.ml.MappedAnalytic.evaluate(MappedAnalytic.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:113) ~[spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:102) ~[spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:49) ~[spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:347) ~[spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88) ~[spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131) ~[spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:330) ~[spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:166) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:317) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:155) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:93) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
2017-03-11T12:24:30+0530 1.3.1.RELEASE ERROR MQTT Call: xd.mqtt.client.id.src inbound.MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter - Lost connection:MqttException; retrying...
```

thanks a lot.  this is update error-log message, after recommendation:

```
2017-03-12T00:21:11+0530 1.3.1.RELEASE ERROR MQTT Ping:          xd.mqtt.client.id.src inbound.MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter - Lost    connection:Timed out waiting for a response from the server; retrying...
2017-03-12T00:25:02+0530 1.3.1.RELEASE ERROR MQTT Rec: xd.mqtt.client.id.src   server.NIOServerCnxnFactory - Thread Thread[MQTT Rec:    xd.mqtt.client.id.src,5,main] died
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:          org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/internal/wire/MqttReceivedMessage
at     org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.wire.MqttWireMessage.createWireMessage(MqttWireMessage.java:189) ~[na:na]
at          org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.wire.MqttWireMessage.createWireMessage(M     qttWireMessage.java:163) ~[na:na]
at    org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.wire.MqttInputStream.readMqttWireMessage     (MqttInputStream.java:83) ~[na:na]
at     org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:107    ) ~[na:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:       org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.wire.MqttReceivedMessage
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~        [na:1.8.0_101]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at       org.springframework.xd.module.support.ParentLastURLClassLoader.loadClass(ParentL    astURLClassLoader.java:87) ~[spring-xd-module-    1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
... 5 common frames omitted
2017-03-12T00:26:11+0530 1.3.1.RELEASE ERROR MQTT Ping:      xd.mqtt.client.id.src inbound.MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter - Lost   connection:Timed out waiting for a response from the server; retrying...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pmml module expects a `Tuple` - try adding `--outputType=application/x-xd-tuple` to the mqtt source definition

```
xd:>stream create test --definition "mqtt --url='tcp://localhost:1883' --topics='irisPayload' --outputType=application/x-xd-tuple | analytic-pmml ...
```

**EDIT**

I tested it with a TCP source...

```
xd:>stream create --name pmml1 --definition "tcp --outputType=application/x-xd-tuple | analytic-pmml --modelName=iris-flower-classification-naive-bayes-1 --location=/Users/grussell/Downloads/spring-xd-modules-master/analytics-ml-pmml/src/test/resources/analytics/pmml/iris-flower-classification-naive-bayes-1.pmml.xml --inputFieldMapping='sepalLength:Sepal.Length,sepalWidth:Sepal.Width,petalLength:Petal.Length,petalWidth:Petal.Width' --outputFieldMapping='Predicted_Species:predictedSpecies' | log" --deploy
```

And used `telnet localhost 1234` to send:

```
{ "sepalLength": 6.4, "sepalWidth": 3.2, "petalLength":4.5, "petalWidth":1.5 }
```

and it worked fine.

**EDIT2**

I just tested with MQTT and no problems...

```
2017-03-11T11:25:58-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE INFO xdbus.pmml1.1-1 sink.pmml1 - 
{"sepalLength":6.4,"sepalWidth":3.2,"petalLength":4.5,"petalWidth":1.5,"predictedSpecies":"versicolor"}
```

Stream:

```
xd:>stream create --name pmml1 --definition "mqtt --topics=pmml --outputType=application/x-xd-tuple | analytic-pmml --modelName=iris-flower-classification-naive-bayes-1 --location=/Users/grussell/Downloads/spring-xd-modules-master/analytics-ml-pmml/src/test/resources/analytics/pmml/iris-flower-classification-naive-bayes-1.pmml.xml --inputFieldMapping='sepalLength:Sepal.Length,sepalWidth:Sepal.Width,petalLength:Petal.Length,petalWidth:Petal.Width' --outputFieldMapping='Predicted_Species:predictedSpecies' | log" --deploy
```

**EDIT3**

Here is a DEBUG log (for category `org.springframework.integration` in logback.groovy) from my test; I suggest you compare yours to this one to figure out where things go wrong...

```
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG MQTT Call: xd.mqtt.client.id.src channel.DirectChannel - preSend on channel 'output', message: GenericMessage [payload={"sepalLength":6.4,"sepalWidth":3.2,"petalLength":4.5,"petalWidth":1.5}, headers={mqtt_duplicate=false, mqtt_retained=false, mqtt_qos=0, id=a4f09671-c617-bfce-c2f7-e1844a8772ff, mqtt_topic=mqtt-subscription-xd/mqtt/client/id/srcqos0, contentType=application/x-java-object;type=org.springframework.xd.tuple.DefaultTuple, timestamp=1489253888127}]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE INFO MQTT Call: xd.mqtt.client.id.src kryo.CompositeKryoRegistrar - registering [40, java.io.File] with serializer org.springframework.integration.codec.kryo.FileSerializer
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE INFO MQTT Call: xd.mqtt.client.id.src kryo.CompositeKryoRegistrar - registering [41, org.springframework.xd.tuple.DefaultTuple] with serializer org.springframework.xd.tuple.serializer.kryo.DefaultTupleSerializer
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE INFO MQTT Call: xd.mqtt.client.id.src kryo.CompositeKryoRegistrar - registering [42, java.util.ArrayList] with serializer com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG MQTT Call: xd.mqtt.client.id.src outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint - org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint@2cc14cf received message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[89], headers={mqtt_duplicate=false, mqtt_retained=false, mqtt_qos=0, id=58499b9d-6a38-ea36-ac8e-93c704d61a1b, mqtt_topic=mqtt-subscription-xd/mqtt/client/id/srcqos0, contentType=application/x-java-object;type=org.springframework.xd.tuple.DefaultTuple, originalContentType=application/x-java-object;type=org.springframework.xd.tuple.DefaultTuple, timestamp=1489253888135}]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG MQTT Call: xd.mqtt.client.id.src mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[mqtt_duplicate] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG MQTT Call: xd.mqtt.client.id.src mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[mqtt_retained] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG MQTT Call: xd.mqtt.client.id.src mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[mqtt_qos] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG MQTT Call: xd.mqtt.client.id.src mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[mqtt_topic] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG MQTT Call: xd.mqtt.client.id.src mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[contentType] WILL be mapped, found in [amqp_appId, amqp_clusterId, amqp_contentEncoding, amqp_contentLength, contentType, amqp_correlationId, amqp_deliveryMode, amqp_deliveryTag, amqp_expiration, amqp_messageCount, amqp_messageId, amqp_receivedExchange, amqp_receivedRoutingKey, amqp_redelivered, amqp_replyTo, amqp_timestamp, amqp_type, amqp_userId, json__TypeId__, json__ContentTypeId__, json__KeyTypeId__, amqp_springReplyCorrelation, amqp_springReplyToStack]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG MQTT Call: xd.mqtt.client.id.src mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[originalContentType] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG MQTT Call: xd.mqtt.client.id.src outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint - handler 'org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint@2cc14cf' produced no reply for request Message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[89], headers={mqtt_duplicate=false, mqtt_retained=false, mqtt_qos=0, id=58499b9d-6a38-ea36-ac8e-93c704d61a1b, mqtt_topic=mqtt-subscription-xd/mqtt/client/id/srcqos0, contentType=application/x-java-object;type=org.springframework.xd.tuple.DefaultTuple, originalContentType=application/x-java-object;type=org.springframework.xd.tuple.DefaultTuple, timestamp=1489253888135}]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG MQTT Call: xd.mqtt.client.id.src channel.DirectChannel - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'output', message: GenericMessage [payload={"sepalLength":6.4,"sepalWidth":3.2,"petalLength":4.5,"petalWidth":1.5}, headers={mqtt_duplicate=false, mqtt_retained=false, mqtt_qos=0, id=a4f09671-c617-bfce-c2f7-e1844a8772ff, mqtt_topic=mqtt-subscription-xd/mqtt/client/id/srcqos0, contentType=application/x-java-object;type=org.springframework.xd.tuple.DefaultTuple, timestamp=1489253888127}]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[amqp_receivedRoutingKey] WILL be mapped, found in [amqp_appId, amqp_clusterId, amqp_contentEncoding, amqp_contentLength, contentType, amqp_correlationId, amqp_deliveryMode, amqp_deliveryTag, amqp_expiration, amqp_messageCount, amqp_messageId, amqp_receivedExchange, amqp_receivedRoutingKey, amqp_redelivered, amqp_replyTo, amqp_timestamp, amqp_type, amqp_userId, json__TypeId__, json__ContentTypeId__, json__KeyTypeId__, amqp_springReplyCorrelation, amqp_springReplyToStack]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[amqp_deliveryTag] WILL be mapped, found in [amqp_appId, amqp_clusterId, amqp_contentEncoding, amqp_contentLength, contentType, amqp_correlationId, amqp_deliveryMode, amqp_deliveryTag, amqp_expiration, amqp_messageCount, amqp_messageId, amqp_receivedExchange, amqp_receivedRoutingKey, amqp_redelivered, amqp_replyTo, amqp_timestamp, amqp_type, amqp_userId, json__TypeId__, json__ContentTypeId__, json__KeyTypeId__, amqp_springReplyCorrelation, amqp_springReplyToStack]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[amqp_redelivered] WILL be mapped, found in [amqp_appId, amqp_clusterId, amqp_contentEncoding, amqp_contentLength, contentType, amqp_correlationId, amqp_deliveryMode, amqp_deliveryTag, amqp_expiration, amqp_messageCount, amqp_messageId, amqp_receivedExchange, amqp_receivedRoutingKey, amqp_redelivered, amqp_replyTo, amqp_timestamp, amqp_type, amqp_userId, json__TypeId__, json__ContentTypeId__, json__KeyTypeId__, amqp_springReplyCorrelation, amqp_springReplyToStack]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[contentType] WILL be mapped, found in [amqp_appId, amqp_clusterId, amqp_contentEncoding, amqp_contentLength, contentType, amqp_correlationId, amqp_deliveryMode, amqp_deliveryTag, amqp_expiration, amqp_messageCount, amqp_messageId, amqp_receivedExchange, amqp_receivedRoutingKey, amqp_redelivered, amqp_replyTo, amqp_timestamp, amqp_type, amqp_userId, json__TypeId__, json__ContentTypeId__, json__KeyTypeId__, amqp_springReplyCorrelation, amqp_springReplyToStack]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[mqtt_duplicate] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[mqtt_retained] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[mqtt_qos] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[mqtt_topic] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[contentType] WILL be mapped, found in [amqp_appId, amqp_clusterId, amqp_contentEncoding, amqp_contentLength, contentType, amqp_correlationId, amqp_deliveryMode, amqp_deliveryTag, amqp_expiration, amqp_messageCount, amqp_messageId, amqp_receivedExchange, amqp_receivedRoutingKey, amqp_redelivered, amqp_replyTo, amqp_timestamp, amqp_type, amqp_userId, json__TypeId__, json__ContentTypeId__, json__KeyTypeId__, amqp_springReplyCorrelation, amqp_springReplyToStack]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[originalContentType] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 channel.DirectChannel - preSend on channel 'pmml1.0.bridge', message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[89], headers={amqp_deliveryTag=1, mqtt_retained=false, amqp_consumerQueue=xdbus.pmml1.0, amqp_redelivered=false, originalContentType=application/x-java-object;type=org.springframework.xd.tuple.DefaultTuple, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=xdbus.pmml1.0, mqtt_duplicate=false, mqtt_qos=0, id=b325de8d-e28b-0c6c-e3e2-54e8ab22c66d, mqtt_topic=mqtt-subscription-xd/mqtt/client/id/srcqos0, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-rXY4nOqwizbePkGVpCulcg, contentType=application/x-java-object;type=org.springframework.xd.tuple.DefaultTuple, timestamp=1489253888152}]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 channel.DirectChannel - preSend on channel 'input', message: GenericMessage [payload={"sepalLength":6.4,"sepalWidth":3.2,"petalLength":4.5,"petalWidth":1.5}, headers={amqp_receivedRoutingKey=xdbus.pmml1.0, amqp_deliveryTag=1, mqtt_duplicate=false, mqtt_retained=false, amqp_consumerQueue=xdbus.pmml1.0, amqp_redelivered=false, mqtt_qos=0, id=62a6601c-d4db-8e33-ab97-1e5ffd17a56f, mqtt_topic=mqtt-subscription-xd/mqtt/client/id/srcqos0, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-rXY4nOqwizbePkGVpCulcg, contentType=application/x-java-object;type=org.springframework.xd.tuple.DefaultTuple, timestamp=1489253888166}]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 transformer.MessageTransformingHandler - org.springframework.integration.config.TransformerFactoryBean#0 received message: GenericMessage [payload={"sepalLength":6.4,"sepalWidth":3.2,"petalLength":4.5,"petalWidth":1.5}, headers={amqp_receivedRoutingKey=xdbus.pmml1.0, amqp_deliveryTag=1, mqtt_duplicate=false, mqtt_retained=false, amqp_consumerQueue=xdbus.pmml1.0, amqp_redelivered=false, mqtt_qos=0, id=62a6601c-d4db-8e33-ab97-1e5ffd17a56f, mqtt_topic=mqtt-subscription-xd/mqtt/client/id/srcqos0, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-rXY4nOqwizbePkGVpCulcg, contentType=application/x-java-object;type=org.springframework.xd.tuple.DefaultTuple, timestamp=1489253888166}]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 channel.DirectChannel - preSend on channel 'output', message: GenericMessage [payload={"sepalLength":6.4,"sepalWidth":3.2,"petalLength":4.5,"petalWidth":1.5,"predictedSpecies":"versicolor"}, headers={amqp_receivedRoutingKey=xdbus.pmml1.0, amqp_deliveryTag=1, mqtt_duplicate=false, mqtt_retained=false, amqp_consumerQueue=xdbus.pmml1.0, amqp_redelivered=false, mqtt_qos=0, id=e4e5e571-581c-24e2-6d08-73bd1340d483, mqtt_topic=mqtt-subscription-xd/mqtt/client/id/srcqos0, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-rXY4nOqwizbePkGVpCulcg, contentType=application/x-java-object;type=org.springframework.xd.tuple.DefaultTuple, timestamp=1489253888276}]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint - org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint@6c6a8365 received message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[119], headers={amqp_deliveryTag=1, mqtt_retained=false, amqp_consumerQueue=xdbus.pmml1.0, amqp_redelivered=false, originalContentType=application/x-java-object;type=org.springframework.xd.tuple.DefaultTuple, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=xdbus.pmml1.0, mqtt_duplicate=false, mqtt_qos=0, id=7ffad6d0-db78-8ffd-cc9d-7619e9359834, mqtt_topic=mqtt-subscription-xd/mqtt/client/id/srcqos0, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-rXY4nOqwizbePkGVpCulcg, contentType=application/x-java-object;type=org.springframework.xd.tuple.DefaultTuple, timestamp=1489253888276}]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[amqp_deliveryTag] WILL be mapped, found in [amqp_appId, amqp_clusterId, amqp_contentEncoding, amqp_contentLength, contentType, amqp_correlationId, amqp_deliveryMode, amqp_deliveryTag, amqp_expiration, amqp_messageCount, amqp_messageId, amqp_receivedExchange, amqp_receivedRoutingKey, amqp_redelivered, amqp_replyTo, amqp_timestamp, amqp_type, amqp_userId, json__TypeId__, json__ContentTypeId__, json__KeyTypeId__, amqp_springReplyCorrelation, amqp_springReplyToStack]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[mqtt_retained] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[amqp_consumerQueue] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[amqp_redelivered] WILL be mapped, found in [amqp_appId, amqp_clusterId, amqp_contentEncoding, amqp_contentLength, contentType, amqp_correlationId, amqp_deliveryMode, amqp_deliveryTag, amqp_expiration, amqp_messageCount, amqp_messageId, amqp_receivedExchange, amqp_receivedRoutingKey, amqp_redelivered, amqp_replyTo, amqp_timestamp, amqp_type, amqp_userId, json__TypeId__, json__ContentTypeId__, json__KeyTypeId__, amqp_springReplyCorrelation, amqp_springReplyToStack]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[originalContentType] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[amqp_receivedRoutingKey] WILL be mapped, found in [amqp_appId, amqp_clusterId, amqp_contentEncoding, amqp_contentLength, contentType, amqp_correlationId, amqp_deliveryMode, amqp_deliveryTag, amqp_expiration, amqp_messageCount, amqp_messageId, amqp_receivedExchange, amqp_receivedRoutingKey, amqp_redelivered, amqp_replyTo, amqp_timestamp, amqp_type, amqp_userId, json__TypeId__, json__ContentTypeId__, json__KeyTypeId__, amqp_springReplyCorrelation, amqp_springReplyToStack]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[mqtt_duplicate] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[mqtt_qos] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[mqtt_topic] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[amqp_consumerTag] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[contentType] WILL be mapped, found in [amqp_appId, amqp_clusterId, amqp_contentEncoding, amqp_contentLength, contentType, amqp_correlationId, amqp_deliveryMode, amqp_deliveryTag, amqp_expiration, amqp_messageCount, amqp_messageId, amqp_receivedExchange, amqp_receivedRoutingKey, amqp_redelivered, amqp_replyTo, amqp_timestamp, amqp_type, amqp_userId, json__TypeId__, json__ContentTypeId__, json__KeyTypeId__, amqp_springReplyCorrelation, amqp_springReplyToStack]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint - handler 'org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint@6c6a8365' produced no reply for request Message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[119], headers={amqp_deliveryTag=1, mqtt_retained=false, amqp_consumerQueue=xdbus.pmml1.0, amqp_redelivered=false, originalContentType=application/x-java-object;type=org.springframework.xd.tuple.DefaultTuple, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=xdbus.pmml1.0, mqtt_duplicate=false, mqtt_qos=0, id=7ffad6d0-db78-8ffd-cc9d-7619e9359834, mqtt_topic=mqtt-subscription-xd/mqtt/client/id/srcqos0, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-rXY4nOqwizbePkGVpCulcg, contentType=application/x-java-object;type=org.springframework.xd.tuple.DefaultTuple, timestamp=1489253888276}]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 channel.DirectChannel - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'output', message: GenericMessage [payload={"sepalLength":6.4,"sepalWidth":3.2,"petalLength":4.5,"petalWidth":1.5,"predictedSpecies":"versicolor"}, headers={amqp_receivedRoutingKey=xdbus.pmml1.0, amqp_deliveryTag=1, mqtt_duplicate=false, mqtt_retained=false, amqp_consumerQueue=xdbus.pmml1.0, amqp_redelivered=false, mqtt_qos=0, id=e4e5e571-581c-24e2-6d08-73bd1340d483, mqtt_topic=mqtt-subscription-xd/mqtt/client/id/srcqos0, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-rXY4nOqwizbePkGVpCulcg, contentType=application/x-java-object;type=org.springframework.xd.tuple.DefaultTuple, timestamp=1489253888276}]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 channel.DirectChannel - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'input', message: GenericMessage [payload={"sepalLength":6.4,"sepalWidth":3.2,"petalLength":4.5,"petalWidth":1.5}, headers={amqp_receivedRoutingKey=xdbus.pmml1.0, amqp_deliveryTag=1, mqtt_duplicate=false, mqtt_retained=false, amqp_consumerQueue=xdbus.pmml1.0, amqp_redelivered=false, mqtt_qos=0, id=62a6601c-d4db-8e33-ab97-1e5ffd17a56f, mqtt_topic=mqtt-subscription-xd/mqtt/client/id/srcqos0, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-rXY4nOqwizbePkGVpCulcg, contentType=application/x-java-object;type=org.springframework.xd.tuple.DefaultTuple, timestamp=1489253888166}]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.0-1 channel.DirectChannel - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'pmml1.0.bridge', message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[89], headers={amqp_deliveryTag=1, mqtt_retained=false, amqp_consumerQueue=xdbus.pmml1.0, amqp_redelivered=false, originalContentType=application/x-java-object;type=org.springframework.xd.tuple.DefaultTuple, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=xdbus.pmml1.0, mqtt_duplicate=false, mqtt_qos=0, id=b325de8d-e28b-0c6c-e3e2-54e8ab22c66d, mqtt_topic=mqtt-subscription-xd/mqtt/client/id/srcqos0, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-rXY4nOqwizbePkGVpCulcg, contentType=application/x-java-object;type=org.springframework.xd.tuple.DefaultTuple, timestamp=1489253888152}]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.1-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[amqp_receivedRoutingKey] WILL be mapped, found in [amqp_appId, amqp_clusterId, amqp_contentEncoding, amqp_contentLength, contentType, amqp_correlationId, amqp_deliveryMode, amqp_deliveryTag, amqp_expiration, amqp_messageCount, amqp_messageId, amqp_receivedExchange, amqp_receivedRoutingKey, amqp_redelivered, amqp_replyTo, amqp_timestamp, amqp_type, amqp_userId, json__TypeId__, json__ContentTypeId__, json__KeyTypeId__, amqp_springReplyCorrelation, amqp_springReplyToStack]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.1-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[amqp_deliveryTag] WILL be mapped, found in [amqp_appId, amqp_clusterId, amqp_contentEncoding, amqp_contentLength, contentType, amqp_correlationId, amqp_deliveryMode, amqp_deliveryTag, amqp_expiration, amqp_messageCount, amqp_messageId, amqp_receivedExchange, amqp_receivedRoutingKey, amqp_redelivered, amqp_replyTo, amqp_timestamp, amqp_type, amqp_userId, json__TypeId__, json__ContentTypeId__, json__KeyTypeId__, amqp_springReplyCorrelation, amqp_springReplyToStack]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.1-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[amqp_redelivered] WILL be mapped, found in [amqp_appId, amqp_clusterId, amqp_contentEncoding, amqp_contentLength, contentType, amqp_correlationId, amqp_deliveryMode, amqp_deliveryTag, amqp_expiration, amqp_messageCount, amqp_messageId, amqp_receivedExchange, amqp_receivedRoutingKey, amqp_redelivered, amqp_replyTo, amqp_timestamp, amqp_type, amqp_userId, json__TypeId__, json__ContentTypeId__, json__KeyTypeId__, amqp_springReplyCorrelation, amqp_springReplyToStack]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.1-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[contentType] WILL be mapped, found in [amqp_appId, amqp_clusterId, amqp_contentEncoding, amqp_contentLength, contentType, amqp_correlationId, amqp_deliveryMode, amqp_deliveryTag, amqp_expiration, amqp_messageCount, amqp_messageId, amqp_receivedExchange, amqp_receivedRoutingKey, amqp_redelivered, amqp_replyTo, amqp_timestamp, amqp_type, amqp_userId, json__TypeId__, json__ContentTypeId__, json__KeyTypeId__, amqp_springReplyCorrelation, amqp_springReplyToStack]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.1-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[mqtt_duplicate] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.1-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[mqtt_retained] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.1-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[mqtt_qos] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.1-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[mqtt_topic] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.1-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[contentType] WILL be mapped, found in [amqp_appId, amqp_clusterId, amqp_contentEncoding, amqp_contentLength, contentType, amqp_correlationId, amqp_deliveryMode, amqp_deliveryTag, amqp_expiration, amqp_messageCount, amqp_messageId, amqp_receivedExchange, amqp_receivedRoutingKey, amqp_redelivered, amqp_replyTo, amqp_timestamp, amqp_type, amqp_userId, json__TypeId__, json__ContentTypeId__, json__KeyTypeId__, amqp_springReplyCorrelation, amqp_springReplyToStack]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.1-1 mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher - headerName=[originalContentType] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.1-1 channel.DirectChannel - preSend on channel 'pmml1.1.bridge', message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[119], headers={amqp_deliveryTag=1, mqtt_retained=false, amqp_consumerQueue=xdbus.pmml1.1, amqp_redelivered=false, originalContentType=application/x-java-object;type=org.springframework.xd.tuple.DefaultTuple, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=xdbus.pmml1.1, mqtt_duplicate=false, mqtt_qos=0, id=78a3106d-46cb-c3ac-f5df-8f1d1deb6c68, mqtt_topic=mqtt-subscription-xd/mqtt/client/id/srcqos0, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-Jjdp9-tezFirzMm72oL8kA, contentType=application/x-java-object;type=org.springframework.xd.tuple.DefaultTuple, timestamp=1489253888279}]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.1-1 channel.DirectChannel - preSend on channel 'input', message: GenericMessage [payload={"sepalLength":6.4,"sepalWidth":3.2,"petalLength":4.5,"petalWidth":1.5,"predictedSpecies":"versicolor"}, headers={amqp_receivedRoutingKey=xdbus.pmml1.1, amqp_deliveryTag=1, mqtt_duplicate=false, mqtt_retained=false, amqp_consumerQueue=xdbus.pmml1.1, amqp_redelivered=false, mqtt_qos=0, id=7d15c204-5ee1-600d-3bda-45abf7059dac, mqtt_topic=mqtt-subscription-xd/mqtt/client/id/srcqos0, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-Jjdp9-tezFirzMm72oL8kA, contentType=application/x-java-object;type=org.springframework.xd.tuple.DefaultTuple, timestamp=1489253888279}]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.1-1 handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler#0 received message: GenericMessage [payload={"sepalLength":6.4,"sepalWidth":3.2,"petalLength":4.5,"petalWidth":1.5,"predictedSpecies":"versicolor"}, headers={amqp_receivedRoutingKey=xdbus.pmml1.1, amqp_deliveryTag=1, mqtt_duplicate=false, mqtt_retained=false, amqp_consumerQueue=xdbus.pmml1.1, amqp_redelivered=false, mqtt_qos=0, id=7d15c204-5ee1-600d-3bda-45abf7059dac, mqtt_topic=mqtt-subscription-xd/mqtt/client/id/srcqos0, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-Jjdp9-tezFirzMm72oL8kA, contentType=application/x-java-object;type=org.springframework.xd.tuple.DefaultTuple, timestamp=1489253888279}]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE INFO xdbus.pmml1.1-1 sink.pmml1 - {"sepalLength":6.4,"sepalWidth":3.2,"petalLength":4.5,"petalWidth":1.5,"predictedSpecies":"versicolor"}
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.1-1 channel.DirectChannel - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'input', message: GenericMessage [payload={"sepalLength":6.4,"sepalWidth":3.2,"petalLength":4.5,"petalWidth":1.5,"predictedSpecies":"versicolor"}, headers={amqp_receivedRoutingKey=xdbus.pmml1.1, amqp_deliveryTag=1, mqtt_duplicate=false, mqtt_retained=false, amqp_consumerQueue=xdbus.pmml1.1, amqp_redelivered=false, mqtt_qos=0, id=7d15c204-5ee1-600d-3bda-45abf7059dac, mqtt_topic=mqtt-subscription-xd/mqtt/client/id/srcqos0, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-Jjdp9-tezFirzMm72oL8kA, contentType=application/x-java-object;type=org.springframework.xd.tuple.DefaultTuple, timestamp=1489253888279}]
2017-03-11T12:38:08-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG xdbus.pmml1.1-1 channel.DirectChannel - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'pmml1.1.bridge', message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[119], headers={amqp_deliveryTag=1, mqtt_retained=false, amqp_consumerQueue=xdbus.pmml1.1, amqp_redelivered=false, originalContentType=application/x-java-object;type=org.springframework.xd.tuple.DefaultTuple, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=xdbus.pmml1.1, mqtt_duplicate=false, mqtt_qos=0, id=78a3106d-46cb-c3ac-f5df-8f1d1deb6c68, mqtt_topic=mqtt-subscription-xd/mqtt/client/id/srcqos0, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-Jjdp9-tezFirzMm72oL8kA, contentType=application/x-java-object;type=org.springframework.xd.tuple.DefaultTuple, timestamp=1489253888279}]
```

Comment: still getting the same error.  can you please explain me about the starting lines of errors, which is:-       2017-03-11T21:34:37+0530 1.3.1.RELEASE ERROR MQTT Call: xd.mqtt.client.id.src inbound.MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter - Unhandled exception for GenericMessage [payload={
  "sepalLength": "6.4",
  "sepalWidth":  "3.2",
  "petalLength": "4.5",
  "petalWidth":  "1.5"
}, headers={mqtt_retained=false, mqtt_qos=0, id=88ada5ea-7588-43fb-82c4-847c2c1fb6ac, mqtt_topic=irisPayload, mqtt_duplicate=false, timestamp=1489248276597}]

Comment: It just means the downstream exception was thrown back to the MQTT adapter. I tested it with TCP - see my edit - I tested with MQTT too - see the second edit.

Comment: I found slight difference in your stream definition as mine. what is the purpose of modelName? I am giving the location of my model pmml.xml file.  thanks you so much Sir, without you, it's not at all possible for me to get such clarity/

Comment: I am not really familiar with the module; I just followed the information in the [configuration XML file](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd-modules/blob/master/analytics-ml-pmml/src/main/resources/config/analytic-pmml.xml) and tweaked it for a TCP/MQTT source. But having that property or not won't cause the `ClassCastException` you are seeing - that's a more fundamental problem indicating we can't get the data to the model.

Comment: through telnet also, I tried to sent data. getting an error - I got clarity that data is not reached to model. just last thing can u please upload a snap of how you are publishing data via MQTT broker. I tried two way to publish data to the broker, first one via Python script and second via rabbit-mq management console.  thanks.

Comment: I simply pasted `{ "sepalLength": 6.4, "sepalWidth": 3.2, "petalLength":4.5, "petalWidth":1.5 }` into the `payload` field on the RabbitMQ admin UI (under __Publish Message__ for the queue `mqtt-subscription-xd.mqtt.client.id.srcqos0`) and clicked __Publish Message__.

Comment: @ Gary Russell, I also followed the same step. I updated the error-log in question. I am thinking some problem with my channel adapter or with a broker. thanks for your patience guidance.

Comment: That's a different problem; before, you were clearly getting a message to the pmml module `at org.springframework.xd.analytics.ml.pmml.TuplePmmlAnalyticInputDataMapper.mapInput(TuplePmmlAnalyticInputDataMapper.java:37) ~[na:na]`. Now you're getting a weird `NoClassDefFoundError` in the mqtt module - you must have changed something else. It looks like some kind of weird class loader problem. Perhaps start with a clean XD installation?

Comment: I added a DEBUG log from my test; perhaps you could compare yours to figure out where things go awry.

Comment: thanks. now everything is working fine. modelName is a name of our classification model and in the stream, we must have to specify that. the only problem is now my MQTT plugin-broker running in rabbitmq is allowed to connected to one stream at a time. so next time when, I am creating new stream it shows error log something like this--2017-03-13T00:19:52+0530 1.3.1.RELEASE ERROR task-scheduler-2 inbound.MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter - Exception while connecting and subscribing
org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException: Client is connected

Comment: You can add `clientId` to the stream definition - it defaults to `clientId = "xd.mqtt.client.id.src"`.